# How do i set xsi:nil="true" with lxml

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I'm asked to set some fields attributes xsi:nil="true" and i'm getting ValueError: Invalid attribute name 'xsi:nil'

I've tried the next code:

```py
from lxml import etree as ET

element = ET.Element(element_name)
sub_element = ET.SubElement(element, 'sub_element_name')
sub_sub_element = ET.SubElement(element_name, sub_sub_element_name, {'xsi:nil':"true"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sub_sub_element = ET.SubElement(element_name, sub_sub_element_name,  { "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil" : "true" } )
```

See https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces.